Laplace transform of $\sin(\omega t)$
I am learning about the Laplace transform and I know I got the answer to this example question wrong, but I'm trying to figure out if I just made a calculus or algebra type error, or if I'm misunderstanding something about the Laplace transform itself. Does anyone see where I went wrong below?
I'm trying to find the Laplace transform of $\sin(\omega t)$, in other words, $\mathcal{L}(\sin(\omega t); s)$. I know the answer is $\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$, but I don't know how to get there. This is in the context of LTI systems.
Here's what I tried.
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin(\omega t); s) = \int_0^\infty \sin(\omega t) e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t$$
Now I'm not sure how to formally notate this part, but I think $$\int \sin(\omega t) e^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{-1}{s}\sin(\omega t)e^{-st}$$ and I need to evaluate that expression at $\infty$ and $0$ and subtract them.
At $0$, that would be $$\frac{1}{s}\sin(0)e^0 = \frac{1}{s} \cdot 0 \cdot 1 = 0$$
So I just need to evaluate it at $\infty$. This value will only exist when the real part of $s$ is positive, because then $e^{-st}$ goes to 0 as $t$ goes to $\infty$ instead of going to $\infty$. But in that case, isn't the whole expression now $0$? How do I end up with $\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$?
I'm thinking this involves representing the sinusoidal part of the expression as an exponential expression, but I don't see how that would change the problem/confusion I am running into.

Your indefinite integral is incorrect - try differentiating it with respect to $t$ and you'll see that it's different.

Have a look here.

There are a few ways to find $\int \sin(\omega t) e^{-s t} dt$. One way is via integration by parts, and another is by using Euler's identity $e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x$ to relate the integral to one that involves only exponential functions.
However you approach it, you will get the same answer as Wolfram Alpha, which is
$$\int \sin(\omega t) e^{-s t} dt = -\frac{e^{-st} (s \sin(\omega t) + \omega \cos(\omega t))}{s^2 + \omega^2} + C$$
You can then evaluate that indefinite integral at $t = 0$ and as $t \rightarrow \infty$ to get the expression for the Laplace transform.


I think $\int sin(\omega t) e^{-st} dt = \frac{-1}{s}sin(\omega t)e^{-st}$

You would be incorrect. You're correct in that
$$
\int e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t
= - \frac 1 s e^{-st}+C
$$
but you've in no way treated or accounted for the sine function!
The typical way this one is done is with integration by parts. For the basic case without an $\omega$ or $s$ constant, you would have
$$
\int \sin(x) e^{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sin x e^x - \cos x e^x - \int \sin x e^x \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
You can see this yourself, or by computing it with the tabular method as below:

Solving for the desired integral then yields
$$
\int \sin x e^x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac 1 2 e^x \Big( \sin x - \cos x \Big) + C
= \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} e^x \sin \left( x - \frac \pi 4   \right)  + C
$$
where the final simplification comes from using the harmonic addition formula (MathWorld; blackpenredpen) if desired (but also probably not needed).
